# Apex replay debugger is throwing Java 8 is required to run

Tags: salesforce, visual-studio-code, apex, vscode-debugger

I am following [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/find-and-fix-bugs-with-apex-replay-debugger/apex-replay-debugger-debug-your-code) trail and I have completed all the steps correctly. Even I able to download the debug logs. 
But Problem occurs when I am trying to run the following command

```
> SFDX: Launch Apex Replay Debugger with Current File
```

It shows the below error.

[image]

But, the thing is, I have jdk-12.0.1 installed on my PC. After that, I have installed the Java 8 also and thus jdk-1.8.0_181 is also installed.

[image]

My Java Home setting in VS code is following

[image]

I have also restarted my PC, But no luck. It is throwing the same error.

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the path as 'C://Program Files//Java//jdk1.8.0_181' and then restart the vs code

Answer (score 0):

In case any Mac users needed help:

I installed Java 11 and then ran this code: 
`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`  to find the exact directory and then pasted it in the user settings you have marked with a red rectangle. Then I restarted VS code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Looked at your screenshots...

You did this: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181`

You wanted this: `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181`

From the Trailhead unit you linked: 
[image: File Path on Windows]